# Data load in dropdown menu is taking too much time for big data

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a dropdown menu in my form that contains thousand of data to be shown. So far I have tried following code. I am receiving all the data but when I click on this dropdown menu it is taking too much time to load the data. Can anybody help me how can I optimize my code.

```
$.fn.addSelect2Items = function(items, config){
    var that = this;
    that.select2("destroy");
    for(var k in items){
        var data = items[k];
        that.append("<option value='"+ data.id +"'>"+ data.text +"</option>");
    }
    that.select2(config || {});
};
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
    arr.push("testData "+i);        
}
var data = {
     dataCat1 : arr
}


$("select").select2({data: data.dataCat1});
$("button").click(function(){
    $("select").addSelect2Items([{id: 3, text: "novo"}], {});
});
```

Please look at my jsfiddle for working code. Thank You.

http://jsfiddle.net/zan/9nbzwLjd/17/

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you could do is not try to put 200,000 items in a dropdown menu. It's just not the right interface for selecting between that many items. There are other things you could do to make this code run faster, but the basic concept is still flawed even if you optimize it.

Comment: It would depend what the real choices would be -- I'm guessing not like your test data. Would the real choices have some sort of natural hierarchical relationship? Are they so varied that it might just be better to have the user type something in?

Comment: I will have those data retrieved from database which is approximately around huge number. This data are list of serial numbers.